# An unbreakable iPhone charging cable

Tags: smartphones, power

I tend to carelessly yank my iPhone and iPad off of their charging cables, which leads to either the metal connector tip coming off or causes the cable to fray.  As a result, I go through iPhone cables like I go through socks.

So my question is, are there any (nearly) unbreakable iPhone cables that stand up to such wear and tear?  I've tried numerous brands of nylon-braided cables.  They tend to solve the "cables fraying" issue, but the metal connector tips keep coming off.

The only cable I've come across that claims to protect the connector is the ["Snakable"](https://www.snakable.com/) cable, but it's only 4 feet long.  I want a cable that's 6 feet or longer.

Comment: What's your budget? Are you looking for a 30pin cable or a lightning cable?

Comment: @0-60FPS I'm looking for a lightning cable, and budget isn't really a consideration for me.  I just want something good.

Comment: I am just surprised that you haven't damaged the internal parts of the connector.

Comment: Solution: yank iPhone off cable carefully.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Well, for better or worse that's not going to happen, so I want another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic Znaps perhapz: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1041610927/znaps-the-9-magnetic-adapter-for-your-mobile-devic

There are similar products available on sites like DealExtreme and AliExpress, and also available for Android and any other devices that use micro USB or USB-C.

Comment: Or he could, you know, treat his equipment as if he gave a rats behind about it.

Comment: Not for me to decide. I'm just trying to help with the problem at hand.

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting solution.  But from what I can tell, the magnet is incredibly weak, and it disconnects at the slightest motion.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Well, I *don't* give a rat's behind about it. :-)

Comment: I doubt that since it's mean to be used pretty much like you described it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  I wish I was in a position to say money is no object and that I have no qualms about damaging my equipment as I'll just get replacements.......Actually, even if money wasn't an object I would likely still take care of my stuff.

Comment: There's still the issue with infants. I think an alternative solution has its right. I'll try Znaps myself.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Pride of ownership? Get the crazy nonsense out of here! When I unplug my phone I just baseball throw it hard enough that the cable pops off... isn't that how its supposed to be done?

Comment: @Big  Dear lord, thanks for the laugh, needed that after dealing with traffic.

Comment: @StephanHenningsen Did you ever try out Znaps?  If so how is it?